Markdown editing packages running under react generate visual bugs when built in a docker image (api platform app)
I have an API running under PHP Symfony 6.4 with the API Platform overlay. The back office of this application runs under next 12 with React admin.
I have a package in my back office allowing me to edit Markdown in order to create personalized popup messages.
In this application, my back office works very well when I deploy it "the old way" on an Ubuntu server or when I launch it locally on Ubuntu, Mac OS or WSL2 when I use a Docker compose.
On the other hand, when I launch a Dockerfile which contains the entire App to deploy my API + my back office in a single image. The Markdown editor no longer works properly and I have visual bugs that prevent me from editing posts correctly. When I build locally via "docker build", I have the problem just like when I deploy under Kurbernetes.
Here is my Dokcerfile :
# Description: Dockerfile for the API Platform application
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.3
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.20

########################################################################################
# Step 1: Build PHP from linux/amd64
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm as php_builder

# Install necessary dependencies for API Platform & nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    nginx \
    gnupg \
    software-properties-common \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    pdo \
    pdo_pgsql \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# Install Composer 
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Copy the project files into the working directory
COPY . .

# Install dependencies with Composer
WORKDIR /var/www/app/api
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"
COPY api/composer.json api/composer.lock api/symfony.lock ./
RUN set -eux \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts --no-progress \
    composer clear-cache

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync
RUN composer install

# Generate the autoloading files
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize

########################################################################################
# Step 2: Build the PWA
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as pwa_builder
    
WORKDIR /var/www/app/pwa
COPY pwa/ /var/www/app/pwa/
# Installation des dépendances et construction de la PWA
RUN yarn install \
    && yarn build \
    && yarn next export

########################################################################################
# Step 3: Start of the production stage
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine as php_prod

# Set environment variables
ENV APP_ENV=prod \
    APP_DEBUG=0 \
    PROJECT_DIRECTORY=my_app \
    PROJECT_DOMAIN=my_app 

# Install necessary dependencies for API Platform & nginx
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    icu-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    nginx \
    gnupg \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    pdo \
    pdo_pgsql \
    zip \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
    
# Allow memory limit to the maximum available
RUN echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ram-limit.ini;

# Copy the necessary files from the builder stages
COPY --from=php_builder /var/www/app/api /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/api
COPY --from=pwa_builder /var/www/app/pwa/out /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/pwa/out

# Copy the Nginx configuration file for API Platform 
# it must match with the nginx alpine image
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY
COPY /docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/entrypoint.sh

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY

# Set permissions
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/api
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/api

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/entrypoint.sh"]


With the bug :

I tried another package and same problem, I had visual bugs.
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
    "react-mde": "^11.5.0",

I also tried to install font packages on my alpine image to feed the package but It does not work. Then finaly, I tried to build on an Ubuntu image but it was unsuccessfull & the image was too big.
Have you ever encounter this kind of problem ?

It seems that markdown pages may not be served correctly due to my nginx configuration. Please note, the URLs of the pages that are causing me problems do not end in ".md" because I just have part of my page that contains markdown in a react component

EDIT : Solved
I solved the problem by adding this lines in my file nginx.conf. Those lines allow serving css before accessing "_next" other files then it works :
    location /_next/static/css/ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        alias /var/www/my_app/pwa/out/_next/static/css/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        types {
            text/css css;
        }
    }

